# The absence of some mod message-related strings in Transifex

Tags: bug, status-review, moderator-tools, localization

I cannot find these strings using Transifex:

1. > (name hidden from user)

   [image]

---

2. > Regards,
   > {site name} Moderation Team

   [image]

This string does appear in [Transifex](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/136274664?q=key%3Aa540546d1d09e2ea0f26657c37dd3e30) and it seems like this string does not work ok (it is translated and approved, but, unfortunately, not rendered on the site).

---

3. > bcc

   [image]

All of the strings are taken from the mod message (Moderator Private Message) interface.

Could you please fix these issues?

Comment: Note: It looks like the second issue has been fixed already; I tested creating a mod message on SOru, and it included the string "С уважением,    
команда модераторов сайта «Stack Overflow на русском»", matching [what appears in Traducir](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/6424). (The site name is included as a variable, so it works fine on https://rus.stackexchange.com as well.) It may be worth editing the question to focus on the remaining outstanding issue, rather than reporting 2 separate issues in a single post (one of which has already been fixed since this post was originally made).

Comment: @V2Blast to reproduce 2nd issue try to add an additional message to already notified user.

Comment: @V2Blast one more little thing here - word "Notes" also is out of translation scope. Actually not there, but on mod [dashboard root page](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/admin).

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Please report that in another post so I can escalate it properly.

Comment: @V2Blast [done](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389026/339911)