# Unable to translate "Low answer quality score" sentence

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools, low-quality-posts, localization

There's no available source string for "Low answer quality score" on mod flags processing page:

> [image]

Could this please be made available to translate?

Comment: Just a thought, but shouldn't it be "low-quality-answer score" in English in first place?

Comment: @W.O. or "Low answer's quality score"?

Comment: Every time I'm very curious why someone downvotes BR? Just because they don't understand it or what?

Comment: @W.O. It's the score of the answer quality, so while short the current text in English is not wrong.

Comment: Perhaps: "low answer-quality score" might work then. Just seems jarringly ambiguous even if the meaning is obvious on reflection. @Mast

Comment: @W.O. I think "low answer-quality score" is exactly what they had in mind indeed.

Comment: @V2Blast please look for [these strings](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/311613/339911) as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This one is now available for translation as of Aug 2, 2023.

I left the English string exactly as is. My interpretation is "the score given to assess the quality of an answer is low"

Comment: Please take a look at [one more](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/392126/339911)