# "Low answer quality score" translation is not used on "Posts" mod tool page

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, low-quality-posts, localization

Recently, the "Low answer quality score" auto-flag reason was made translatable: [Unable to translate "Low answer quality score" sentence](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/388984/unable-to-translate-low-answer-quality-score-sentence)

Unfortunately on the `/admin/posts` mod-only page (e.g. [here on Stack Overflow in Russian](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/admin/posts)), this translation for "Low answer quality score" is still not being used:

> [image]