# Unable to translate "Low answer quality score" sentence for processed flags with negative score

Tags: bug, flags, moderator-tools, localization, answer-quality

There is no translation possible for "Low answer quality score" on processed flag section. At the same time that phrase has translation for

- a new flag

> [image]

- a processed flag with positive score

> [image]

Another thing and possible the root of issue with translation absence is that the score value is set to [-1]. Before that I can only recall positive values in that part.

Fix for positive values was posted earlier: [Unable to translate "Low answer quality score" sentence](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/388984/339911)