# Unable to translate "Notes" word on moderator dashboard (history) main page

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools, localization, moderation-history

The word "Notes" (above the explanation of the highlighted stats) on the [moderator dashboard](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/admin) (link for staff only) needs to be made translatable:

> [image]

It currently doesn't appear in Traducir, and can't be translated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for the report! "Notes" should be translatable now, along with "No moderators in this community" on the same page.

Comment: Where's "No moderators in this community" located? I didn't see it at all.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ: I think it's a possible message that could appear on a site (i.e. the message exists in the code), but I don't think it's a thing that anyone outside of staff would ever see – since it'd only be shown (in the first section of that page) if the site didn't have any mods :P

Comment: @V2Blast it seems that you need someone in your team who don't speak English :)